# Edit server-side XML file with ASP instead of PHP

Tags: php, asp.net, ajax, xml

I have just migrated an intranet server from Windows Server 2008 and IIS8 to Server 2016 and IIS10 -- everything is good except for one little PHP function-- the rest of the xml manipulation pages are all done in ASP and work just fine-- I have checked and rechecked the PHP install and even tried cloning the  php 5.6 folder from the old server (which also has the php config file) to no avail. No errors are generated in the PHP log file!  I think I prefer to just rewrite the code in ASP, but I think it is much more complicated than the PHP code.  Any help would be greatly appreciated, as my time is limited and I have lots of other tasks occupying me.  Already spent way too much time on this one single function. The basic idea is to look at a particular cid (row) and just toggle the Status from In to Out or vice-versa.  Have a feeling that ASP code may be the faster route than poking around with the PHP installation."

Hoping this is an easy question for the right person.

Calling the function like so:

```
  function change(stat,row) {
 
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "js/update.php",
    data: {status: stat, statrow: row},
    success: function() {
        location.reload();
    }
});
```

The php function:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php 
    
    $status = $_POST['status'];
    $row = $_POST['statrow'];
    $rownum = (int)$row;
    // echo $status," ",$rownum;
    
    // load the document
    // the root node is <Crew_List/> so we load it into $crewlist
    $crewlist = simplexml_load_file('../xml/crew-list.xml');
    //$currstatus = $crewlist->item[$rownum]->Status;
    
    // update
    if ($status == "In") {
        $crewlist->item[$rownum]->Status = "Out";
    } else {
        $crewlist->item[$rownum]->Status = "In";
    }
    
    // save the updated document
    $crewlist->asXML('../xml/crew-list.xml');
    
    // echo "done";
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="true"?>
-<Crew_List>

-<item>
<cid>1</cid>
<Status>Out</Status>
<Name>Crew1</Name>
<Title>Purser</Title>
<Phone_Number>-</Phone_Number>
<EMail/>
</item>

-<item>
<cid>2</cid>
<Status>In</Status>
<Name>Crew2</Name>
<Title>Captain</Title>
<Phone_Number>-</Phone_Number>
<EMail/>
</item>
</Crew_List>
```

Tried lots of stuff with PHP Manager and could not get php function to work.  Works fine on the other server with IIS8 and PHP 5.6

Comment: Have you turned on error reporting for PHP and inspected the logs?

Comment: You can also try to use XSLT to modify XML file. And it is your programming language agnostic, ASP or PHP.

Comment: Yes error reporting is on and nothing in the log.  The PHP code works fine on the old server so I assume it's a problem with the PHP installation since no errors are generated either-- I prefer to try the code in ASP than to spend more time troubleshooting the PHP installation.

Comment: *"no errors are generated"* How do you know that? Did you inspect the output of the script?

Comment: ah.. good call... no just nothing in the PHP log file..I will have to check that

Answer (score 1):

Typically a standard, clean XML is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

Hence, for your XML, please

1. remove the `-` from the following :

```
-<Crew_List>
....
-<item> 
....
-<item>
```

2. remove the `<?xml version="1.0" standalone="true"?>` line (or change to `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`)
3. For sure you need to set the XML file to be writable otherwise the PHP will not be able to update and save the file.

So the following works (tested - 2nd record Status updated from `In` to `Out`):

XML

```
<Crew_List>

<item>
<cid>1</cid>
<Status>Out</Status>
<Name>Crew1</Name>
<Title>Purser</Title>
<Phone_Number>-</Phone_Number>
<EMail/>
</item>

<item>
<cid>2</cid>
<Status>In</Status>
<Name>Crew2</Name>
<Title>Captain</Title>
<Phone_Number>-</Phone_Number>
<EMail/>
</item>
</Crew_List>
```

PHP (as a test I hardcoded the variables to be set by POST)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php 

/*    
    $status = $_POST['status'];
    $row = $_POST['statrow'];
*/

    $status = "In";
    $row = "1"; 

    $rownum = (int)$row;
    
    $crewlist = simplexml_load_file('../xml/crew-list.xml');

     
    if ($status == "In") {
        $crewlist->item[$rownum]->Status = "Out";
    } else {
        $crewlist->item[$rownum]->Status = "In";
    }
  
    // save the updated document
   $crewlist->asXML('../xml/crew-list.xml');
    
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Last but not least, one seldom uses `location.reload();` on success from a ajax call (just a note)

Comment: Hi Thanks so much for your response and insight-- however the PHP code works as expected under IIS8 and Server 2012 with PHP 5.6-- I am looking for the equivalent code for the PHP in ASP... the extra hyphens are getting introduced by the web page interface somehow but since it doesn't affect the performance, I never bothered to track it down...

Comment: `I am looking for the equivalent code for the PHP in ASP` - do you mean **classic ASP**?

Comment: >>do you mean classic ASP?
 ASP.net 2.0-4.5 -- whatever will work with IIS10 the easiest...

Answer (score 0):

Well, to answer my own question, in case anyone needs the same:

I ended up finding a good code [conversion tool](https://codingfleet.com/code-converter/asp.net/)
and it gave me the following asp.net code that works just fine:

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Xml" %>

<script runat="server">
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Request.HttpMethod == "POST")
        {
            string status = Request.Form["status"];
            int rownum = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["statrow"]);

            // load the document
            XmlDocument crewlist = new XmlDocument();
            crewlist.Load(Server.MapPath("../xml/crew-list.xml"));

            // update
            XmlNodeList items = crewlist.GetElementsByTagName("item");
            XmlNode item = items[rownum];
            if (status == "In")
            {
                item["Status"].InnerText = "Out";
            }
            else
            {
                item["Status"].InnerText = "In";
            }

            // save the updated document
            crewlist.Save(Server.MapPath("../xml/crew-list.xml"));
        }
    }
</script>
```